# Background from CSS not working in Base.html

Tags: html, css, background-image, gradient, css-gradients

The following base.html code is not implementing the gradient background from the css file that is in the same folder.

base.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="templates/css/style.css">
  </head>

<body>
<h1>hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #faaca8, #ddd6f3);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

}

Comment: If it's in the same folder, why does the href is not set to ./style.css ?

Comment: you mean it's not working at all? or just not covering the entire page like you want it to?

Comment: Change your `link` to `<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="style.css">` - you're currently trying to go into the folder /templates from your current position, which clearly doesn't make sense as the css is in the current folder.

Comment: check you css path.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not working, the problem is going to be the fact that you are referring to a different directory than you are wanting for the style.css folder. If it's in the same folder, please change the href in the link to `href="style.css"`.

This is assuming you have one folder with the base.html and in the SAME folder, there is also the style.css stylesheet .

If it's based on the root directory, you would use `/style.css` , or on the folder before, `../foldername/style.css`. For more, [read here.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Put the css codes inside the body tag or you can do it like this

```css
   body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #faaca8, #ddd6f3);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">  </head>
    
    <body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
    
    
   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

text="text/css" should read type="text/css"